# Prevent scaling of background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically I have this project where I'm trying to make a magnifying glass.
The problem I encountered is that for a really zoomed in pictures, I don't have a clean zoom.

When I zoom on one screenshot, I get this:

[image: IE2]

---

I would like to get this:

[image: IE 1]

Don't mind the scale here, I'm talking about the blurring effect!
I think it's due to the fact that I'm using background size property to power my zoom and that it'sscaling the image. How can I prevent that from happening and keep a neat PNG zoom?

### SOLVED

I have my solution thanks to you all. I added this to my css styles.

```
image-rendering: pixelated;
```

I works fine for me on recent Chrome version.

Comment: You use an appropriately sized image...

Comment: By the way, "converting the source to jpg" is incorrect, it's _aliasing_ it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm not a native speaker and I never heard that expression. I tried to formulate it with my little knowledge